# store log file on network, instead of windows/system32

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm successfully running this powershell script, but unfortunately most of the script is in C# I have no skill with.

https://hinchley.net/2013/11/03/creating-a-key-logger-via-a-global-system-hook-using-powershell/

Here is the line with the name of the log file.

```
private const string logFileName = "keymylog.txt";
```

I found no path, but it's always stored in windows/system32/. I tried to add the path before the name of the file, but it didn't work. Is it possible to change it to network storage i.e. //192.168.5.5/a/log.txt ? Thank you

Comment: Use backslashes, and keep in mind the escape rules of C#, so `logFileName = @"\\192.168.5.5\a\log.txt"`. But obviously better is to make this parameterizable -- give `Main` a `string logFileName` parameter and you can pass it from PowerShell.

Comment: I'm C# noob, @"\\...." did it, please create an answer and Thank you very much!